# Don't be in a Hurry or Don't be Hurry

Tags: idioms

Consider that we want to say a sentence with meaning in negative form of "hurry up!". Which one is true?

- Don't be in a hurry
- Don't be hurry

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "negative form"? Do you mean you don't want the person to hurry? Or that you want it to sound derisive?

Comment: "Do not hurry" would be sufficient to express that you do not wish someone to 'hurry up'. Do not be in a hurry is somewhat long-winded for expressing the same concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Don't be hurry" is not grammatically correct. "Hurry" in the instance of your first sentence is a noun, and, therefore, needs the "a". So your first sentence is correct.

If you want to use "hurry" as a verb, you can say "Don't be hurried" (though that still sounds awkward) or "Don't hurry".

Answer (score 4):

Technically, neither.

"Hurry up" contains a verb in the imperative mode and active voice.   The most direct way to negate this clause as it stands is simply "Don't hurry up."   In the negative, the intransitive preposition "up" doesn't sound natural.   I'd simply say "Don't hurry."

There's nothing wrong with the sentence "Don't be in a hurry."   The word "hurry" can serve as a noun and act as the object of a preposition.   Although the grammar of this sentence is different, the meaning is much the same.

There *is* something wrong with the sentence "Don't be hurry."   However, it's very close to the correct statement "Don't be hurried." The form "hurried" is the past participle form.   We can interpret "hurried" as either part of a passive voice construction or as a predicate adjective subject complement.

The form "hurry" can act as a noun, but not as an adjective.   If we take it to be a noun, then "Don't be hurry" has the same pattern as "Don't be a fool."   In "Don't be a fool", the noun "fool" and the subject of the sentence have the same referent -- both are the person spoken to.   However, the noun "hurry" makes no sense when referring to a person.   It refers instead to an abstract quality.

Answer (score 3):

"Don't be in a hurry is correct"
You can also use "Don't rush" or "Don't be hasty" instead

Comment: Welcome to ELL Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.

1. If you are advising someone about making an important decision, I would say "Don't be (too) hasty" or "Don't be in too much of a hurry" (i.e: take your time making the decision, as it is important and you don't want to make the wrong decision). You can also say "I wouldn't rush into anything straightaway..." implying the person should think carefully before deciding.
2. If you are telling someone not to worry about being a bit late, I would say: "No need to rush " or "No need to hurry". "Don't hurry" is also correct in this context, but not in (1). It would usually be natural to qualify the "No need to hurry" or "Don't hurry" imperative with a reassuring concluding statement thus: "No need to hurry. Better late than never" or "Don't hurry. Take your time - I'm in no rush."

Hope that helps?